# how to write the javascript code to get the effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

mysite have two searches, one is the whole site search. another is google search.

the html structure is :

```
<div class="fr_search">        
      <select class="search_l">
        <option value="0">the whole site search</option>
         <option value="1">google search</option>
      </select>

    <form action="1.php"  method="post" id="search-theme-form">      
   <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="search_theme_form" id="edit-search-theme-form-1" size="15" value="" title="input search term" class="form-text" />
   <input type="image" name="submit" id="edit-submit"  class="form-submit"     src/images/search_btn_top.gif" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-9fb5cf2703f7df33fe84873222db2cbe" value="form-9fb5cf2703f7df33fe84873222db2cbe"  />
   <input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-search-theme-form"   value="search_theme_form"  />  
</form>
```

now,  i want to do is when the site vistor select "the whole site search" from the  drop-down list . when he input the term in the textbox, and click the submit button, the search result he get coming form the site.

when the vistor select "google search" fromm the  drop-down list . when he input the search term in the textbox, and click the submit button,  the search result he get coming form the  Google Custom Search .
thank you.

Comment: will this be on select? or after he submits the form?

Comment: Not sure - I'm assuming after the submit image is clicked, since it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#edit-submit").click(function() {
    if ($(".search_l")[0].val() == "0") {
        // site search
        $("#search-theme-form").submit();
    } else {
        // google
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + $("#edit-search-theme-form-1").attr("value");
    }
});
```

Comment: Just noticed you specified Google Custom Search - not sure how the URL would be built (or if would actually still need to post to a page).